# How to select corresponding ID in sql

Tags: php, sql, database

I am new to php and I am trying to make a school portal, and right now I am trying to create the page where admins can make the classes.
All I need to know how to do is allow the admin to select a teacher (names or username come directly from database) from the drop down menu, and enter the corresponding ID into my 'class' table, in teacher_id.

```
$query = "SELECT Username FROM tbluser WHERE Role='Teacher'";
$result2= mysqli_query($conn, $query);
<body>

            <form action="createclass.php" method="POST">
                <div>
                    <label>Class name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="classname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new username">
    <br/>
                    <label>Teacher</label>
                    <select name ="teacher">
                        <option  selected = "true" disabled="disabled"> Select one from below...</option>
                        <?php 
                            while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
                            {
                                $teachername= $rows['Username'];
                                echo"<option value ='$teachername'>$teachername</option>";
                            }
                         ?>
                    </select>
```

```
    if(isset($_POST["btnAddclass"])){

        $classname = $_POST["classname"];
        $teacher = $_POST["teacher"];
        $subject = $_POST["subject"];
        $section = $_POST["section"];
        $yeargroup = $_POST["yeargroup"];

    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ID FROM teacher INNER JOIN tbluser ON tbluser.ID=teacher.tbluser_ID WHERE Username = '$teacher'"); // using mysqli_query instead

    $sql = "INSERT INTO class (classname, teacher_id, yeargroup_id, subject_id, section_id) VALUES ('$classname', '$result1', '$subject','$section','$yeargroup')"; 
    if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
    {
        echo "Error";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "New class has been added.";
    }

    }
```

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5mP8.png)

Comment: Why not `option value ='$teachedID'`?

Answer (score 0):

Also select `ID` from tbluser, this ID is a teacher ID:

```
$query = "SELECT ID, Username FROM tbluser WHERE Role='Teacher'";
$result2= mysqli_query($conn, $query);

<form action="createclass.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label>Class name</label>
        <input type="text" name="classname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new username">
        <label>Teacher</label>
        <select name="teacher">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled"> Select one from below...</option>
            <?php 
            while ($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {?>
            <option value="<?php echo $rows['ID']?>"><?php echo $rows['Username']?></option>
            <?php
            }?>
        </select>
```

On submit:

```
$classname = $_POST["classname"];
$teacherID = $_POST["teacher"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$section = $_POST["section"];
$yeargroup = $_POST["yeargroup"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO class (classname, teacher_id, yeargroup_id, subject_id, section_id) VALUES ('$classname', '$teacherID', '$subject','$section','$yeargroup')";
```

And as you use **unsafe** data from user input, consider moving to **prepared statements** to avoid SQL injections.